# Trying to import existing Perforce Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, perforce

I have imported Perforce Project to my local Drive and then i create workspace in Eclipse Luna, but when i try to import project using **File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace** then i select root directory of my project. Import wizard scans whole project and then gives me the warning
`No projects are found to import`. I know the project that i am importing does not have any .classpath and project file. Is there any straight forward way to import the project from Local directory ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import Existing Projects will only import **Eclipse** projects - which always have a .project file.

To import something else you will first have to create an appropriate project in Eclipse with 'File > New > Project....'. Once you have the project you can use 'File > Import > File System' to import the project files in to your new project.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have .classpath and project files it's not an eclipse project. Import from filesystem.